# Issue Open Excel file By Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, internet-explorer

I have a problem that is I export 1000 records and file name is "ExportTemplate.xls" by IE, I use open file not save. It's okay. Then I filter and I export 500 records  and file name is"ExportTemplate.xls", I use open file not save but Excel open 1000records not 500 records.
I realized that when I export 1000records Excel file by IE, It's be stored at C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files with name is "ExportTemplate.xls", then I export 500records it's not be replace this file.
With Firefox and Chrome is okay.
So how to solve my problem?

Comment: I don't understand the problem temporary files are just that temporary and will be removed or deleted. What is the purpose of replacing another file in temporary directory?

Comment: Second time I click Export button to export 500 records. I open by IE, I dont save this file. But Excel app only show 1000 records that I export on first time. I open Internet Options of IE click Settings under Browser History, I see path of temp folder C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files. I do second export IE not save this export in temp folder. It only open excel which i export on first export.